# How to avoid the pain of CSS multi-browser compatibility?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I need to do a CSS layout. I need to know the best practices to avoid the pain of the CSS multi-browser compatibility.

What I should use to avoid issues in this regard? Should I use a CSS Framework? If yes which one?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, know your audience; this lets you know what browsers your site will be accommodating. Second, make sure you have a good grasp of [CSS](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css). Third, get familiar with the concept of ["progressive enhancement."](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/progressiveenhancementwithcss) Lastly, consult this website: [Do websites need to look exactly the same in every browser?](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

For starters, good clear code, thats styled once, and once only helps LOADS. When i say this, I mean, insure all your CSS is in an external file, and no in page or in line css calls are made.

Second, start with a good body,html statement. Get everything defaulted from the work go, your margins, your padding, font size and family, maybe simple calls, but doing it as this step, will save you countless calls of code later on. Even more so when dealing with large sites with 100's of lines of CSS code.

Lastly, keep your CSS organised, make comments, put them into catagories.

Most cross browser related issues are down to one thing, user error. Style it right, style it once, and you and your users will be happy!

Answer (score 1):

1. I use [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) as a a starting point for css and html.
2. For a grid-based site, I might also use [Fluid 960 GS](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/)
3. I write my code to be standards compliant first, and cross-browser friendly second. Don't kill yourself for the bad browsers.
4. You can use something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to feature Progressive Enhancement. [Here are some good reasons](http://boagworld.com/design/where-are-my-rounded-corners/) to do this
5. For bad browsers, let's just call it IE, wherever something is breaking, just give it more space, and make sure everything is readable. If you do that, it should look ok, but don't kill yourself trying to make it pixel perfect to the design. You can use that link in point 4 to explain to your client / boss why it isn't the same in every browser, and why that's a good thing, not bad.
6. If you can do all that, your code will be nicer to write, quicker to run and much closer to being future-proof.

If all else fails, use padding instead of margins whenever you can, and things will be more consistent when viewed in IE. And if you're supporting IE6 try and not use too many transparent png images.

Answer (score 0):

There are some other good suggestions here, but I'll add one: YUI's [reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) stylesheet. It gets rid of some of the more obvious incompatibility problems, without adding a whole lot of page weight.

Answer (score 0):

[QuirksMode.org](http://quirksmode.org) is an excellent resource for browser compatibility information.